# How do I change the color of a vertex in C# OpenGL?

Tags: c#, opengl

I want to change the color of a few vertices under an event but I cannot seem to make it work.

How is the usual procedure done when you want to change a vertex color?

I have an initialization where I give instructions on how the cube is going to be made and a onRenderFrame(); where I draw the cube so the shape and color are already set but I cannot seem to manage to make a color change under an event (like an if-statement).

I will send the whole code. It also involves a connection between Arduino which will play part in the color change

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using OpenGL;
namespace Arduino
{
class Program
{
    private static int width = 1200, height = 720;
    private static ShaderProgram program;
    private static VBO<Vector3> squareColor;
    private static VBO<Vector3> square;
    private static VBO<int> squareElements;
    private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch;
    private static float angle;
    private static bool exitWhile = false;
    private static bool initOK = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while(exitWhile == false)
        {
            if(initOK == true)
            {
                Init();
            }

        }

    }
    private static void Init()
    {

        Glut.glutInit();
        Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);
        Glut.glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
        Glut.glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Arduino");
        SerialPort myArduino = new SerialPort();
        myArduino.BaudRate = 9600;
        myArduino.PortName = "COM3";
        myArduino.Open();
        myArduino.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Comm);

        Glut.glutIdleFunc(OnRenderFrame);
        Glut.glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);

        Glut.glutCloseFunc(OnClose);

        Gl.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        program = new ShaderProgram(VertexShader, Fragmentshader);

        program.Use();
        program["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f, (float)width / height, 0.1f, 1000f));
        program["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.UnitY));

        square = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector3(-1, 1, -1), new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, -1, 1), new Vector3(-1, -1, 1), new Vector3(-1, -1, -1), new Vector3(1, -1, -1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), new Vector3(-1, -1, 1), new Vector3(1, -1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, -1, -1), new Vector3(-1, -1, -1), new Vector3(-1, 1, -1), new Vector3(1, 1, -1),
            new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), new Vector3(-1, 1, -1), new Vector3(-1, -1, -1), new Vector3(-1, -1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, -1, 1), new Vector3(1, -1, -1) });

        squareColor = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1) });

        squareElements = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 }, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);

        watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        initOK = false;
        Glut.glutMainLoop();
    }

     static void Comm(Object Sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)Sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.Write(indata);


        if (indata.Contains("1.10"))
        {
            Vector3[] vertexBuffer = (new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
            new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1) });

            squareColor.BufferSubData(vertexBuffer);
        }

    }

    private static void OnClose()
    {
        square.Dispose();
        squareColor.Dispose();
        squareColorChange.Dispose();
        squareElements.Dispose();
        program.DisposeChildren = true;
        program.Dispose();
        exitWhile = true;
    }

    private static void OnDisplay()
    {

    }
    private static void OnRenderFrame()
    {
        watch.Stop();
        float deltaTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f;
        watch.Restart();

        angle += deltaTime;

        Gl.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
        Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        program.Use();

        //Square draw
        program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0)));
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(square, program, "vertexPosition");
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(squareColor, program, "vertexColor");
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(squareColorChange, program, "vertexColor");
        Gl.BindBuffer(squareElements);

        Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Quads, squareElements.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);

        Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
    }
    public static string VertexShader = @"
        in vec3 vertexPosition;
        in vec3 vertexColor;
        out vec3 color;
    uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
    uniform mat4 view_matrix;
    uniform mat4 model_matrix;

    void main(void)
    {
        color = vertexColor;
        gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1);
    }
  ";
    public static string Fragmentshader = @"
    in vec3 color;
    out vec4 fragment;
    void main(void)
    {
        fragment = vec4(color, 1);
    }
  ";
}
```

It may look a little rough and that's because I am pretty new in both C# and asking questions on Stackoverflow.

I edited the code by adding a subBuffer to my event, although it does not render the new color anyway. Have I forgotten to do something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways to change the color of a vertex but without any code shown, I won't be guessing which one will suit your needs.

Comment: Still not obvious what OpenGL library you are using. But there should be a method in `VBO` class to update the buffer data. So you can use it to change values within your `squareColor` VBO.

Comment: If you read my edited code I have tried to update squareColor with a subBuffer but it does not render on my cube so I may have forgotten to do something.